# MySQL ON Duplicate key syntax error

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make use of the "ON DUPLICATE KEY" query through PHP. Here's what it looks like

```
INSERT INTO `application`.`invites` (`from`, `to`) VALUES ('123', '321') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `from`=VALUES(from), `to`=VALUES(to)
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from), `to`=VALUES(to)' at line 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need backticks around `from` and `to`, everywhere you use them:

```
INSERT INTO `application`.`invites` (`from`, `to`)
    VALUES ('123', '321')
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `from` = VALUES(`from`), `to` = VALUES(`to`)
```

In fact, these are very bad names for columns.  You should avoid using reserved words as column names.